# Unity instance not saved between scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script `Planet.cs` like :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Planet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

In a custom function I need to generate multiple planets, so I create a new GameObject, I add the component Planet (my script), and I set My attribute like :

```
        GameObject planet2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        planet2.AddComponent<Planet>();

        Planet planetCompo2 = planet2.GetComponent<Planet>();
        planetCompo2.Name = "Planet 2";
```

If I check in the end of my function, all attributes are setted, If I check the attribute Name of any planets it's ok.

My problem is, in another script, I try to get a `Planet` from a GameObject with component Planet, but I always have a null Object.

Example : `this.gameObject.GetComponent<Planet>()` or `this.GetComponent<Planet>()` are always null where `this` is the GameObject with Planet Component.

Why my instances are not saved ? What my error ? Thanks !

Comment: In the "another script", are you sure the planet is already instantiated before calling GetComponent ? Nothing wrong in your code, probably a script loading order problem.

Comment: Yes, in the another script, The GameObject "this" is the GameObject clicked in my scene, so he is real :) A script loading order problem ?

Comment: waitwaitwait. Something strange with what you think "this" is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.gameObject.GetComponent<Planet>()` and `this.GetComponent<Planet>()` are both the-same thing since they will both try to get the `Planet` component from the this GameObject **this** script is attached to.

The thing to look at for here is `this`. You are referring to this script. When you do that from another script, you are trying to the `Planet` component from this script that is executing the `GetComponent` function. If this script does not have the `Planet` component, you get `null`. I am sure this is what's happening.

I would suggest naming the GameObject you just created:

```
GameObject planet2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
planet2.AddComponent<Planet>();
//Name it
planet2.name = "Your Other GameObject";
```

Now, find the GameObject from another script then access the `Planet` component from it:

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Your Other GameObject");
//Now you can do 
Planet planetCompo2 = obj.GetComponent<Planet>();
```

---

Since you already have the variable `Name` in your `Planet` script, you can all `Planet` script with GetComponent[s] then just loop through it and check which one has the name "*Planet 2*".

```
Planet planetCompo2 = null;

//Get all Planet components
Planet[] tempComPlanet = GetComponents<Planet>();

//Seatch for which one has the name "Planet 2"
for (int i = 0; i < tempComPlanet.Length; i++)
{
    if (tempComPlanet[i].Name == "Planet 2")
    {
        //Found. Store it to planetCompo2 then exit the loop
        planetCompo2 = tempComPlanet[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the GameObject.Find("someStringHere") find an object by it's name in the editor? And what happens if there are multiple entities with the same name?

Comment: *"Does the GameObject.Find("someStringHere") find an object by it's name in the editor?"*  **Yes**.  *"And what happens if there are multiple entities with the same name?"* It finds the first one only. If you plan to use it make sure that your object names are unique. If two objects have the-same name but under different objects then you can use "/" to find it as a folder name which is cool. For example, two Door Objects under different Objects: `GameObject.Find("House/Door");` and `GameObject.Find("Car/Door");`

Comment: I think I have another thing, I'm working on a Clone on the real GameObject Planet. Is this a problem ? Do the clone either copy the instance of the component Planet ?

Comment: Planet clonePlanet = GameObject.Instantiate(My_Original_planet, GameObject.Find("SolarSystem").transform);

Comment: Yeah I think is that, if I check "My_Original_planet.Name" it's ok, but "clonePlanet.Name" is null

Comment: I don't like that code. You will probably run into problems later on. My advice is to only use `GameObject.Instantiate` on a prefab. After the cloning, you can then manually copy the value of each components to one another. If all need is for the position and rotation to match, just copy them individually. Not hard. some would do it with reflection. **Don't**. Just copy what you need to be the-same one by one.

Comment: Yeah, I know now it's not a good solution :) Thanks for help I will think about that ;)

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyword 'this' in your other script will reference that object looking for a Planet script attached to it. You should either look for the Game Object that has the script attached or instantiate one.

Apply a tag like *PlanetObject* to your game object with the planet script and use something like the following:

```
var planet = GameObject.FindWithTag("PlanetObject").GetComponent<Planet>();
```